# Loading external image in local HTML inside UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, afnetworking

I have an `NSString` containing `HTML` string with external image URL. For example,

```
NSString *HTMLString = @"<p><img src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/image.jpg" /></p>";
```

When I use `UIWebView` to load HTML and present it in my app, the app freeze until the `UIWebView` done loading the web view.

Is that an issue about the download of image is not asynchronous? I try to find related topic but I can't get the answer.
How to make my image to be downloaded asynchronously?

Background: The HTML string is already loaded asynchronously using `AFNetworking`. All the text can be shown without loading the image. However, the process of downloading image freezes my app.

Comment: Do you want to display an image from a URL string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but if you want to show an image from a URL you can do that easily with a `UIImageView` like this:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com/image.jpg"]]];
```

Or if you want a `UIWebView` you could do a separate HTML file and load it like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Or you can test to add tags like *html*, *body* etc.

I'm open for more info about your problem.

Comment: Does this require two separated view (UIWebView and UIImageView)? I think UIWebView can render images inside a html file, is there any way to load them asynchronously without using extra view?